# Perform search algorithm on two pandas columns and group accordingly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list:

```
L = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
```

I also have a dataframe

```
To    From
 A     B
 B     C
 D     C
 L     M
 M     N
 N     O
```

I am trying to perform a 'search and group' for each element of the list. For example, if we performed a search on the first element of the list, 'A', the following group would be returned.

```
To    From
 A     B
 B     C
 D     C
```

My thinking is to implement a search tree, but haven't been able to come up with anything close.

Comment: Why would A lead to AB,BC and CD? Is it because they are consecutive? What would be the group returned for B?

Comment: You need the networkx module: `import networkx as nx`

Comment: @Jkind9 Anything 'related' to A would be part of the group. The group returned for B, C, and D would be the exact same. My thinking is to drop the elements in the group from the original list so that I don't attempt to group the same thing a second time

Comment: Your own question :-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen I don't think it is a duplicate because that question drops data and moves it around, here I am trying to build groupings regardless of start point.